# Default or beautiful C/C++ Syntax in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, themes, vscode-extensions

I have no idea what on earth has happened to my VSCode. I am unable to trace which or exactly what extension caused this. But, the C++ syntax coloring and theme looks absolutely ugly.

[image]

I want this,

[image]

How can I get that back? I am unable to figure this out. I uninstalled all C/C++ extensions and still the issue remains.

Comment: I don't see too many differences there. Is it the colored parentheses that bother you in particular?

Comment: @JonathanS., The *parentheses* and the *brackets*.

Comment: would be much easier to understand what you mean if the code was the same.

Comment: the syntax coloring is not a feature of the C++ extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode colorizes brackets and parentheses to make it easier to see which opening bracket belongs to which closing bracket.

You can turn it off in the settings:

[image: Bracket Pair Colorization]

Comment: Jonathan, so this is built-in in the VSCode: https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/09/29/bracket-pair-colorization

Comment: Yes, it is a built-in feature, but it can be turned off via that setting.

Comment: Jonathan, do you prefer it?

Comment: Yes, I prefer having it on. It makes it easier to quickly see the nesting of function calls and lambdas, for example. If I remember correctly, it got turned on by default in a recent-ish VSCode update.

Comment: Can this be turned off via, `c_cpp_properties.json`, `"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be customized there. I only know that it can be changed in the workspace JSON under the `workbench.colorCustomizations` entry (VSCode takes you there if you click the "Workbench: Color Customizations" link in the screenshot I've shown)

Comment: Jonathan, I ended up keeping it, when I realized how useful it is now afterwards.